# In Flutter, Dependencies must specify version number?

Tags: dart, flutter

Typically, you have to add something like

```
dependencies:
  camera: "^0.2.0"
```

to the pubspec.yaml file. What happens if I don't include the version number? It's a small thing, but usually, I find a piece of code and want to test it. At the top, I see something like >>

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
```

Do I have to go to the package's homepage to find the version number?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use `any`

```
dependencies:
  camera: any
```

Having tighter constraints makes it easier for `packages get`/`packages upgrade` to search matching versions because it reduces the solution space, but for simple examples it usually doesn't matter.

`pub` got an improved solver recently that makes `any` much less of a problem than it used to be where `pub` often just timed out when `any` was used.

Comment: Note: You can also use git links.

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer

Comment: i.e. using `any` is equivalent of just typing `camera:` (without keyword)?

Answer (score 19):

as per https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies

> Based on what data you want to provide, you can specify dependencies
>   in two ways. The **shortest** way is to just specify a name:

```
dependencies:
  transmogrify:
```

> This creates a dependency on transmogrify that **allows any version,**
>   and looks it up using the default source, which is pub.dartlang.org.
>   To limit the dependency to a range of versions, you can provide a
>   version constraint:

dependencies:
  transmogrify: ^1.0.0

> This creates a dependency on transmogrify using the default source and
>   allowing any version from 1.0.0 to 2.0.0 (but not including 2.0.0).
>   See Version constraints and Caret syntax for details on the version
>   constraint syntax.

I guess that the real answer to my question is that usually, it's best to specify a major version number ratio **e.g.: ^1.0.0 == 1.0.0 < 2.0.0**. This is to say that this program works and is tested and will keep working with this library dependancy so long as there are no major changes.

Comment: Is this mean, dependencies: transmogrify: will use the last version of this package?

Comment: @AliAzad Yes, `transmogrify:` will use the last version.