# What is the caret sign (^) before the dependency version number in Flutter's pubspec.yaml?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub, semantic-versioning

In the `pubspec.yaml` file of my Flutter project there is a caret (`^`) before the version number of some of the dependencies.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  english_words: ^3.1.5
```

What is its purpose? What does it mean?

**Notes**

- I looked in the [yaml documentation](http://yaml.org/spec/1.0/) but I didn't see anything that made sense.
- Related: [what does Caret sign do in Dart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50146809/what-does-caret-sign-do-in-dart) (but it isn't an XOR operator here)
- Related: [In Flutter, Dependencies must specify version number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50533553/in-flutter-dependencies-must-specify-version-number) (an answer pointed me in the right direction but the question is asking something different)

Comment: The YAML spec you linked to, is a bit outdated, the latest version is 1.2. At the bottom you'll find an index, and if  `^` were  a special token for YAML (it isn't) you would find a link there. Independent of that for many the YAML spec doesn't make much sense ;-)

Answer (score 178, accepted):

The caret sign (`^`) is used for [pub dependencies](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies) in Dart to indicate a range of version numbers are allowed. Specifically, any version from the specified version up to (but not including) the next *non-breaking* version is ok.

- So `^3.1.5` is the same as `'>=3.1.5 <4.0.0'`
- And `^1.2.3` would be the same as `'>=1.2.3 <2.0.0'`

It's shorthand for the longer form.

The `^` is saying, I want to automatically use the most up-to-date package from Pub as long as that update won't break anything in my app.

#### Notes

- The concept of [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) is important here. Read the article at the link if you are not familiar with it.
- [Version constraints documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#version-constraints)
- [Caret syntax documentation](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax)

#### Clarification for versions less than 1.0.0

Originally I had thought that

- `^0.1.2` is the same as `'>=0.1.2 <1.0.0'` ***(wrong!)***

However, that is an incorrect understanding of [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/). When the major version number is `0` (as in the `0` of `0.1.2`), the meaning is that the API is unstable and even minor version number changes (as in the `1` of `0.1.2`) can indicate a breaking change.

The [Semantic Versioning](https://semver.org/) article states:

> Major version zero (0.y.z) is for initial development. Anything may change at any time. The public API should not be considered stable.

and also

> How should I deal with revisions in the 0.y.z initial development
> phase?
>
> The simplest thing to do is start your initial development release at
> 0.1.0 and then increment the minor version for each subsequent release.

Thus, the following is the corrected form:

- `^0.1.2` is the same as `'>=0.1.2 <0.2.0'`

*Thank you to [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563563/3681880) for pointing out my error.*

### See also

- [How do Dart Package Versions work & how should I version my Flutter Plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66201337/how-do-dart-package-versions-work-how-should-i-version-my-flutter-plugins)

Comment: on what basis we added 4.0.0? similar 2.0.0. How we are identifying max versions?

Comment: @jitsm555, the max version is the next major number past the min version. If the min version is `3.1.5`, the major version number is `3`. The next number after `3` is `4` so the the max version is `4.0.0` (that is, anything less than `4.0.0` but not including `4.0.0` itself).

Comment: @Suragch Is an update from `2.0.0` to `2.1.0` also considered a breaking change?

Comment: @iDecode, No,  `2.0.0`  to `2.1.0` is not a breaking change.

Comment: @Suragch Thanks, that means both `2.1.0` and `2.0.1` are not breaking changes for a package at `2.0.0`.

Comment: Please help me understand.

"Specifically, any version from the specified version up to (but not including) the next non-breaking version is ok.

So ^3.1.5 is the same as '>=3.1.5 <4.0.0' "

I think it includes the next non-breaking. The next 'breaking' is 4.0.0 which it will not include that, yes, anything before that is 'non-breaking' right?

So it includes all versions including the next non-breaking, until 4.0.0(which is the breaking change).

I may be thinking about it wrong tho'

Comment: @Frankdroid7, correct.

Answer (score 26):

The caret sign `^` means the specified version and all newer versions that don't introduce breaking changes relative to the specified version.

Dart follows Semantic Versioning and suggests that to be used for package maintainers as well.

Semantic Versioning defines that

- For versions `>= 1.0.0`, the major version needs to be incremented for breaking changes.
- For versions `< 1.0.0`, the minor version needs to be incremented for breaking changes.

**Example:**

`^2.4.3` means `>= 2.4.3 < 3.0.0`

`^0.17.19` means `>= 0.17.19 <0.18.0`

Comment: Thanks for that clarification. I had misunderstood the part about the major version 0.

Comment: Thought about just adding a comment buf was afraid it would become to long.

Answer (score 4):

It means that any new versions of a dependency that does not contain breaking changes will be accepted.

Dart language follows semantic versioning and uses it for package maintainers.

In layman's terms `^1.8.1 means >= 1.8.1 < 2.0.0`