# Why there is a ^ Cap symbol in `pubspec.yaml` file under dependencies

Tags: dart, flutter

I not sure why there is a cap symbol in `pubspec.yaml` file under dependencies. See below image.

[image]

The project is working even without the cap symbol.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the caret sign (^) before the dependency version number in Flutter's pubspec.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563079/what-is-the-caret-sign-before-the-dependency-version-number-in-flutters-pub)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is called [*caret syntax*](https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax):

> Caret syntax provides a more compact way of expressing the most common sort of version constraint. `^version` means "the range of all versions guaranteed to be backwards compatible with the specified version", and follows pub’s convention for semantic versioning.

So in your example, you've got:

- meta: `^1.1.6` - equivalent to `>=1.1.6 <2.0`
- equatable: `^0.2.3` - equivalent to `>=0.2.3 <0.3.0`
- cupertino_icons: `^0.1.2` - equivalent to `>=0.1.2 <0.2.0`