# What does ^ mean in poetry?

Tags: python-poetry

I haven't found it in the docs, but I see in pyproject.toml files in poetry things like:

```
psycopg2-binary="^2.9.1"
```

what does the ^ mean?

Thanks!

Comment: https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements

Comment: In your example, the leftmost nonzero digit of "2.9.1" is "2", and a change to "3" is prevented. So, "^2.9.1" would be interpreted as ">=2.9.1 <3.0.0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can read it as `psycopg2-binary="2.x"`.

The way I see it, is that it's effectively an extension of the `psycopg2-binary="~2.1.0"` convention, which indicates `"2.1.x"`.

EDIT: I got it backwards. Edited so it's correct now. See this post explaining it. [Why there is a ^ Cap symbol in `pubspec.yaml` file under dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55809719/why-there-is-a-cap-symbol-in-pubspec-yaml-file-under-dependencies)

Examples:

```
meta: ^1.1.6 - equivalent to >=1.1.6 <2.0
equatable: ^0.2.3 - equivalent to >=0.2.3 <0.3.0
cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2 - equivalent to >=0.1.2 <0.2.0
```

Answer (score 2):

"The leftmost non-zero number is kept fixed. Any number to the right of it may be incremented." - possibly short enough explanation to be memorized.

Comment: who are you quoting here?

Comment: That is my own attempt at summarizing what I find in the [docs](https://python-poetry.org/docs/dependency-specification/#caret-requirements).

The cases where the specification only contains zeros are not covered, though. One could add "If the specification only contains zeros, the rightmost number may be incremented."