# How to automatically upgrade Flutter dependencies

Tags: flutter, dart-pub

My Flutter project has a dependency `flutter_dotenv` at version `^2.0.1` and I want to automatically upgrade to the new version `^2.0.2`.

I am running the following command to upgrade it:

```
flutter pub upgrade
```

Reference: [Upgrading packages only](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/sdk/upgrading#upgrading-packages-only)

> To update to the latest compatible versions of all the dependencies
>   listed in the pubspec.yaml file, use the upgrade command:
>
> flutter pub upgrade

However nothing seems to happen. `pubspec.yaml` does not change, and the console output does not mention of a new version (which would be enough).

My `pubspec.yaml` looks like this:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_dotenv: ^2.0.1
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```

Answer (score 186, accepted):

Above method works but you can use this command:

```
flutter pub upgrade --major-versions
```

It will update all your dependencies.

Also check "How to correctly add dependencies to avoid **"Version solving failed" error**

Refer to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517680/13500457

Comment: will this update pubspec.yaml as well?

Comment: Yes absolutely @giorgio79

Comment: As of 2 weeks ago there is now a `--tighten` flag, that will update pubspec.yaml for minor changes as well.

Comment: thx @bramp just what I have been looking for!!!!!

Answer (score 39):

Flutter automatically upgrades non-breaking changes based on [semantic versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563079/what-is-the-caret-sign-before-the-dependency-version-number-in-flutters-pub/53563080#53563080). You wouldn't want breaking changes to be automatic. The updates are reflected in `pubspec.lock`, but not `pubspec.yaml`.

There are a couple IDE plugins that can help you to upgrade packages more easily than looking them up one by one on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/).

### Android Studio

[Flutter Pub Version Checker](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/12400-flutter-pub-version-checker)

This plugin highlights any dependencies in `pubspec.yaml` you have that are out of date so that you can choose to update them if you want to.

### Visual Studio Code

[Pubspec Assist](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist)

This plugin makes it super simple to add or update a dependency without going to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/), but you still have to check them one at a time.

Comment: I dont agree with "you wouldnt want breaking changes to be automatic", I prefer to think more like "you dont want any change to be automatic", the posibility of introducing problems based on this is incredible, WDYT?

Comment: @DanielGomezRico, If you don't want any change to be automatic then you can remove the `^` from in front of the version number. However, as long as package developers are following semantic versioning, leaving the `^` is fine, since by definition there will be no breaking changes. But even if there are breaking changes, you still test your app before you release it. In my experience I've only had one experience where a minor change broke something. (And that was Dart 2.8 itself.)

Comment: To me the pain was from some old projects that were made like 2 or 3 years ago, and made them recompile was horrible, finding which of which dependency (there was a list of like 30 dependencies)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759292/13500457 When you use the method you've mentioned it'll take some time, when you move your cursor and press alt + enter to all dependencies so it's better to use this command " flutter pub upgrade --major-versions " also you will not get " Version solving error due to SDK version incompatibility" so use this refer the link for details. Happy coding!

Comment: @Suragch sorry to comment an old answer, but I have a doubt: when you say "Flutter automatically upgrades non-breaking changes based on semantic versioning.", you mean, when you use `flutter pub upgrade` command?

Comment: @GiacomoM, Yes, that's right. (Or on `flutter pub get` if you don't have a pubspec.lock file.) See [All about the Pub command line tool for Flutter and Dart](https://suragch.medium.com/all-about-the-pub-command-line-tool-for-flutter-and-dart-52339d594d96).

Answer (score 8):

Running `pub` won't ever change `pubspec.yaml`. However, it might solve to a version different from the 'base' version specified - the leading [caret](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax) allows pub to solve to:

> the range of all versions guaranteed to be backwards compatible with the specified version

Check in the `pubspec.lock` file and you'll probaby see that pub has already solved to `version: "2.0.2"`

Comment: so the answer to OP "How to automatically upgrade Flutter dependencies" is... 
There is no way?

Comment: @adrianvintu yes there is, check my own answer for this.

Answer (score 5):

For upgrading from very old versions to null safety versions:

```
//Upgrading flutter sdk
flutter upgrade
//Upgrading dart code
dart migrate
// Upgrading all pubspec.yaml package versions
flutter pub outdated --mode=null-safety

// Download all new versions of the packages
dart pub get
```

Upgrading dart code again. At this stage you should correct all issues (manually or using migration guide otherwise "The migration tool didn't start, due to analysis errors" show up.

```
// See list of available fixes
dart fix --dry-run

// Fix all issues automatically
dart fix --apply
```

Refer to [this article](https://medium.com/nerd-for-tech/upgrade-your-old-flutter-projects-to-flutter-version-2-with-null-safety-b42f0f21505f) for more details

Check Flutter migration guide [here](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways of declaring dependency versions:

1. [Caret syntax](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#caret-syntax) - It guarantees backwards compatibility. Example: `^1.3.0`
2. [Traditional syntax](https://dart.dev/tools/pub/dependencies#traditional-syntax) - Great flexibility, many options for your control. Example: `>=1.2.3`

The behavior is similar to `package.json` with Node.js dependency management.

Your chosen way of declaring dependencies in the `pubspec.yaml` will define how the *actual dependencies* will be defined in the `pubspec.lock` file.

Comment: Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
Error on line 11, column 20: Expected comment or line break.
   ╷
11 │   add_2_calendar: >=2.1.3

Answer (score 1):

Even if running `flutter pub upgrade --major-versions` (as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759292/4744263)) doesn't change the `pubspec.yaml` file, try:

> `flutter pub add [dependency]`

The command above will show the message `"[dependency]" is already in "dependencies". Will try to update the constraint.`, and reflect the newest dependency version on the `pubspec.yaml`, if there's one.

Comment: I use flutter pub upgrade --major-versions and it works well