# How to resolve version solving failed in flutter

Tags: flutter

Because `flutter_bloc: 0.21.0` depends on `provider: ^3.0.0` and no versions of `flutter_bloc match: >0.21.0 <0.22.0`, `flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0` requires `provider: ^3.0.0`.
So, because it tells_me that it depends on both `provider: ^4.1.2` and `flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0`, version solving failed.

```
pub get failed (1; So, because tellz_me depends on both provider ^4.1.2 and flutter_bloc ^0.21.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: can you share the pubspec.yaml file packages

Comment: version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.


  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
#  barcode_scan: ^1.0.0
  qr_mobile_vision:
  http: ^0.12.0+2
  shared_preferences: ^0.4.1
  torch: ^0.1.1
  loading: ^1.0.1
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  load:
  connectivity: ^0.4.5+6
  flutter_cupertino_localizations: ^1.0.1
  super_tooltip: ^0.9.0
  percent_indicator: ^2.1.1
  flutter_slidable: ^0.5.4

Comment: provider: ^4.1.2
  image_picker: ^0.6.2+3
  flutter_tags: "^0.4.5"
  flutter_staggered_grid_view: "^0.3.0"
  speech_recognition: "^0.3.0"
  device_info: ^0.4.1+3
  #  flutter_multimedia_picker: ^1.0.3
  flutter_picker:
  http_parser:
  media_picker_builder:
  permission_handler:
  path:
  path_provider:
  thumbnails:
  photo:
  oktoast:
  page_view_indicators: ^1.3.1
  flutter_spinkit: "^4.1.1"
  fluttertoast:
  esys_flutter_share: ^1.0.2
  toast: ^0.1.5
  stories: ^0.1.1
  firebase_messaging: ^6.0.9
  flutter_visualizers: ^0.0.1

Comment: photo_view: ^0.9.1
  image_collage_widget: ^1.0.0
  bubble: ^1.1.9+1
  file_picker: ^1.4.3+2
  video_thumbnail: ^0.2.0
  flutter_sound: ^2.0.3
  video_player: ^0.10.6
  audio_recorder:
#  audio_picker: ^1.0.0
  emoji_picker:
  open_file:
  place_picker: ^0.9.12
  flutter_parsed_text: ^1.1.0
  transparent_image: ^1.0.0
  uuid: ^2.0.1
  intl: ^0.16.1
  undo: ^1.0.1+3
  cached_network_image:
  firebase_auth:
  google_sign_in:
#  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.10+2
  firebase_storage: ^3.0.6
  url_launcher: ^5.4.5
  file: ^5.0.4

Comment: multi_image_picker: ^4.6.6+rc.1
  flutter_absolute_path: ^1.0.6
#  flutter_multiple_image_picker: ^0.0.1
  geolocator: ^5.1.4+2

  google_map_location_picker: ^3.3.2
  keyboard_visibility:
  maps_launcher: ^1.2.0
  autocomplete_textfield: ^1.7.3
  selectable_autolink_text: ^1.3.2
  flutter_linkify: ^3.1.3
  flutter_statusbarcolor:
  flutter_uploader:
  firebase_crashlytics:
  image_cropper:
  flutter_bloc: ^0.21.0

Comment: Please check the upper 4 comments
Thanks in advance

Comment: update your flutter_bloc: ^4.0.0 and all the packages as per latest version

Comment: Then i get this :- 

Because tellz_me depends on image_collage_widget ^1.0.0 which depends on flutter_bloc ^0.21.0, flutter_bloc ^0.21.0 is required.
So, because tellz_me depends on flutter_bloc ^4.0.0, version solving failed.
pub upgrade failed (1; So, because tellz_me depends on flutter_bloc ^4.0.0, version solving failed.)

Comment: what package is that ** tellz_me** ? can you share the link?

Comment: Its just a project name

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215636/discussion-between-sanjeev-sangral-and-tarun-mehta).

Answer (score 0):

you need to use dependency override.

this code is from my project, so path provider was the problem, you need to find the package that makes. the conflict and put it inside the `dependency_overrides`
this will fix your problem.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  file_picker: ^3.0.0
  hive: ^2.0.0
  hive_flutter: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  path_provider: 2.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

See this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517680/13500457

And how to update the dependencies automatically:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/66759292/13500457

I would suggest you to remove all dependencies and run pub get and add the dependencies using the command method, not by copy pasting. See this  or mentioned above:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67517680/13500457

I hope it helps, happy coding!