# Flutter dart null safety migration dont work because of package flutter_template_images

Tags: flutter, dart, package, dependencies, dart-null-safety

I want to migrate my project to null safety but the dependecie `flutter_template_images` is not supporting null safety:

```
Package Name             Current  Upgradable  Resolvable  Latest

direct dependencies:
flutter_template_images  ✗4.0.0   ✗4.0.0      ✗4.0.0      ✗4.0.0

dev_dependencies: all support null safety.
You are already using the newest resolvable versions listed in the 'Resolvable' column.
Newer versions, listed in 'Latest', may not be mutually compatible.
```

I dont know where this package comes from and I dont find it in the pubspec.yaml file. Can I migrate null safety without upgrading this dependencie?

EDIT:
This is my pubspec.yaml file:

```
environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  material_design_icons_flutter: ^4.0.5955

  pdf: ^3.3.0

  path_provider: ^2.0.2

  provider: ^6.0.0

  open_file: ^3.2.1

  intl: ^0.17.0

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.2
  cloud_firestore: ^2.3.0
  get: ^4.1.4
  printing: ^5.4.3
  google_sign_in: ^5.0.5
  firebase_auth: ^3.0.1
  fl_chart: ^0.36.3
  url_launcher: ^6.0.9
  sqflite: ^2.0.0+4
```

Comment: Can you attach your `pubspec.yaml` , as it's mentioned in the error it's a direct dependencies it should be present in file , or it might be a possibility you are using some library which has `flutter_template_images` bundled inside them

Comment: I added the pubspec.yaml file to my question

Comment: Could you update the dart sdk and all libraries to the latest version

Comment: Is there a command to do that?

Comment: Go to Tools -> Flutter -> Flutter Upgrade (this is update your dart sdk) and refer this for [upgrade dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57764070/how-to-automatically-upgrade-flutter-dependencies)

Comment: I think it only updated flutter to the newest version but dart stays the same

Comment: Does this help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55898181/update-dart-sdk-for-flutter , but I think it updated dart also, as I updated the same few days ago using this

Comment: Thank you, after updating, whats next?

Comment: Does It still the same error of `flutter_template_images` not supporting

Comment: Yes I still dont find it in pubspec.yaml... Where else could this dependency be?

Comment: **This project is an internal dependency of the flutter tool, and is not intended to be used directly. It contains images files used in flutter create templates, to avoid checking them into the main Flutter repository, where they would permanently increase the checkout size over time if altered**. - this is what dependency says in it's Readme files says ,  Upgrading the flutter should have resolved the issue

Comment: When upgrading i get this text from console: No dependencies changed.
1 package is discontinued.

Answer (score 1):

It appears the maintainer has not migrated the package to dart-null-safety, you could either wait for the maintainer to migrate the package or clone the package and migrate the package yourself.
Another option could be that you remove the package from your project.

For more clarification [dart-null-safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide)

Comment: I would like to delete this package because I dont use it but the problem is i dont know where this package is from and I cant find it in any file. Do you know how I can find where this package is installed?

Comment: Your error message says it is a direct dependency so I believe you could find it in your pubspec.yaml.

Comment: There is no dependency called flutter_template_images in my pubspec.yaml. So where can i find it?

Comment: Same issue here, nowhere to be found on pubspec but the null-safety check picks it up.