# Flutter - connectivity package

Tags: flutter, dart

How should I add this package to pubspec? Thank you!
[image]

Comment: What are "y" and "x"?

Comment: It says it on the page
https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity

Comment: Those are general placeholders for a version number. That's not actually meant to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the simplest way to install any package

1. Search and open package page on https://pub.dev/
2. Click on the `Installing` tab
3. Copy the line and add to `pubspec.yaml`

So in your case go to https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity/install and paste the code.

Currently it is `connectivity: ^0.4.9`. Use 2 spaces for indentation.

---

In general

Given a version number `MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH`, increment the:

`MAJOR` version when you make incompatible API changes,

`MINOR` version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and

`PATCH` version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

so,
increase PATCH for bug fixes.
increase MINOR for new features without breaking old code
increase MAJOR when using it will break old code.

Comment: And how do I add "<2.0.0" without getting the image error?

Comment: You don't have to.
Read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563079

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your package's pubspec.yaml file:

```
connectivity: ^0.4.9
```

If you want to add constraints, replace the x and y with the lowest version you want, such as 0.4.8+6. See the plugin’s pub.dev page for more versions.

Comment: And how do I add "<2.0.0" without getting the image error?