# What version of plugin, Flutter get/fetch when I add dependency of prerelease version with carat symbol?

Tags: flutter, gradle, dependencies, flutter-dependencies

What version does flutter fetch when I add plugin dependency like below code:

```
dependencies:
  pluginA: ^0.1.8
```

If available versions are `0.1.8+1`, `0.1.9`, `0.2.0` etc.

As I see version ^2.1.3 and '>=2.1.3 < 3.0.0' are equal, but except for the prerelease version.
(checked from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563079/what-is-the-caret-sign-before-the-dependency-version-number-in-flutters-pub#:%7E:text=The%20caret%20sign%20(%20%5E%20)%20is,non-breaking%20version%20is%20ok.&text=It%27s%20shorthand%20for%20the%20longer%20form.) link)

So does flutter fetch the updated patch version of pluginA, or fetch the exact version in my case?

Answer (score 0):

I found my answer, here flutter will fetch the latest patch version of pluginA, and in my case, it is 0.1.9.

It is similar to:
`pluginA: '>=0.1.8 < 0.2.0'`