# Flutter downloads wrong version in pubspec.yaml

Tags: flutter, dart

I have updated my flutter version and also performed flutter pug upgrade as recommended.
But some of the packages were having issues caused by the flutter version. I don't want to downgrade my flutter version but I would like to downgrade the package version as latest version of the package is causing issues and not the old versions (as reported by the community as well).

I specified the package version already but still when I run `flutter pub get` it still downloads the latest version of the package.

Performed `flutter pub cache clean` `flutter pub cache repair` and even `dependency_overrides`. but still every time I run `flutter pub get` the latest version of the package is being downloaded as I have the Cache folder open to check.

Comment: Can you give us a "flutter doctor" and your pubspec.yaml?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

please try to run flutter clean and remove the "^" before the desired version

good:

[image]

wont work:

[image]

check this to see what the caret sign(^) does:

[What is the caret sign (^) before the dependency version number in Flutter's pubspec.yaml?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53563079/what-is-the-caret-sign-before-the-dependency-version-number-in-flutters-pub)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! It did solve my issue. deleted the folder in cache first then specified the version without the "^".

Comment: to use the latest version always you do "pub get" you can use `firebase_core: any`

Comment: Yeah this is so strangely working man.. I got stuck doing `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` and nothing's  change.. What I do before is upgrading version in different branch and when I go back to older branch and pub get again somehow version installed is not the same with the one written in `pubspec.yaml`

Comment: You are awesome! I was searching for this for months!!! It really worked!