# Flutter is using the wrong versions of all my packages

Tags: flutter

As you can see from the image below, flutter is referencing the wrong versions.
Even after moving them into the override section running a `flutter pub cache clean`

What is going on?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is because you are using `caret (^)` sign before each package. By using this sign you are allowing your project to use newer versions of packages.

Easily just remove `^` before each page like below and check again:

```
dependencies:
  firebase_core: 2.4.0
  firebase_messaging: 14.1.4
  ....
```

More info in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53563080/10264008)